# Invalid object name when trying to insert into a temp table

Tags: sql, vbscript, adodb

I'm trying to monitor a mirrored copy of a database. I am running a script that is also capable of performing other checks and some of them are very similar to then one that is causing me problems.

Code that works:

```
  conn.execute "if object_id('tempdb..#logs') is not null drop table tempdb..#logs"
  conn.execute "create table #logs (...'a lot of variables)"
  conn.execute "insert into #logs exec('dbcc sqlperf (logspace)')"
```

Code that does not work:

```
  conn.execute "if object_id('tempdb..#mirrors') is not null drop table tempdb..#mirrors"
  conn.execute "create table #mirrors (...'alot of variables)"
  conn.execute "insert into #mirrors exec('msdb..sp_dbmmonitorresults "&db&",1,0')"
```

The error on invalid object comes when trying to execute the insert in the second example. Is it possible that the string including all of the variables is to long?

I have never worked with Visual Basic before so this might be something obvious.

I have tried to run the code in the SQL server manegment studio and it works perfectly.

Does anyone have any ideas?

G

Comment: The first set of VB code runs successfully as-is or does it only work when you run the SQL code in SSMS?

Comment: @Tom H . It runs as it is. The second example only works in SSMS

Comment: What is `db`? It is the only variable.

Comment: @marc . Yes it is a variable with the name of the db. I have checked the string that is sent and it is the way it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was that I had an open "ADODB.recordset". So when I called "conn.execute" it logged out after each execution and there for it wasn't the same session as before and the temp table was deleted before I could insert into it.

I found out by using the SQL profiler.

Thanks for the help.

G

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad I didn't have to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may not be your code, but a problem with SQL Server itself. I think that there are cases where the log shipping objects can be improperly installed. If you read Spanish then there's an [MSDN forum discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es/sqlserveres/thread/e54b8741-837f-4de2-b450-2c846f8c1913) which looks like it might be useful. Unfortunately, I don't read Spanish, I can't use Google translate behind this firewall, and I couldn't find out anything else about it.

The full error that I get when I try to run your code:

`Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dbmmonitorresults, Line 137
Invalid object name 'msdb.dbo.dbm_monitor_data'.`

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I'm beginning to think that the table "#mirrors" isn't being created. This is very strange